# How to query the Lightning Sync Error records

Tags: query, integration, sobject, documentation, lightning-outlook

Once Lightning Sync is enabled a new report type can be created, selecting LightningSyncError as the primary object.

I would need to query this object in order to get the list of sync errors through an integration. I've done some investigations and as far as I can tell the object behind this report is S2XAdminError. Still, I couldn't find a way to query this object and also I couldn't find any documentation about it.

The only alternative I found is to use the Analytics API and get the data from the report. Still, it's a little cumbersome.

Is there any way of getting this data without using the reports/Analytics API?